# HP Stream 14 Won't Enable Proprietary driver for Realtek Semiconductor Corp wireless card

Tags: networking, drivers, hp, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu v18.4 on my relatively new HP Stream 14 using pendrive linux.  I can access the internet using a usb to ethernet adapter, but can't seem to turn on my wireless card using a keyboard shortcut or terminal commands.

> lsusb

yeilded an output of:

> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 248a:8366
>   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:022a Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

and

> lspci

yeilded the following:

> mike@Phantom-HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$ lspci
>   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
>   00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 35)
>   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 35)
>   00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 35)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 35)
>   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 (rev 35)
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 35)
>   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 35)
>   01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
>   02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822

I have attempted (as far as I know) to take all of the steps outlined in a closely-related thread to my problem: "[SOLVED] wifi not working ubuntu and ubuntu mate on hp stream 11," https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=231915; and have also installed pastebinit as well as ndiswrapper.  My laptop's output can be found at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G68gTNnnMg/

> lspci -vnn

gave the following output:

> mike@Phantom-HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$ lspci -vvnn00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register [8086:2280] (rev 35)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
>   Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: i915
>   Kernel modules: i915
>
> 00:0b.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller [8086:22dc] (rev 35)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
>   Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
>   00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller [8086:22b5] (rev 35) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
>
> 00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:2298] (rev 35)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
>   Kernel modules: mei_txe
>
> 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2284] (rev 35)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
>   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 [8086:22c8] (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B-
>   PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
>   Capabilities: 
>   Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>   Kernel modules: shpchp
>
> 00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 [8086:22ce] (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- TAbort- Reset- FastB2B-
>   PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
>   Capabilities: 
>   Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>   Kernel modules: shpchp
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU [8086:229c] (rev 35)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
>   Kernel modules: lpc_ich
>
> 00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller [8086:2292] (rev 35)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel modules: i2c_i801
>   01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [103c:82bd]
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
>   Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
>   02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 
>   [10ec:b822]
>   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:831b]
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
>   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
>   Kernel modules: r8822be, wl

I have also ran the following:

> mike@Phantom-HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$ lspci | grep Network
>   02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822

Thank you again to anyone who took the time to go thru all of this.  Your help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found out from assistance that I received on Ubuntu Forums that Secure Boot was interfering with my on-board wireless card.

The command:

> sudo modprobe r8822be

Gave an output of:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Required key not available

I disabled secure boot using:

> sudo mokutil --disable-validation

and after restarting the computer and inputing the requested key to disable Secure Boot at start up, my laptop began using it's built-in wireless card without issue.

For more info on how do disable secure boot, the article that helped me resolve my issue can be found at:

[Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Happy Coding Everyone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your final solution. I struggled with this for two days. It turned out to be this. Ubuntu was disabling the wifi driver because of secure boot.